# Checkbox value double output on if else if

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input

whats wrong with this code :

```
function calculateAddOnPrice() {
        if (totalPrice <= 47) {
            var polybags= $('#polybags').is(':checked') ? "0.5" : "0";            
            console.log(polybags);
        }
        else if (totalPrice >= 48 && totalPrice < 71) {
            var polybags = $('#polybags').is(':checked') ? "0.35" : "0";            
            console.log(polybags);
        }
```

So i have the output logged to console.

When totalPrice is less than 47 and i click the checkbox for ON the console looks like this :

```
0.5
```

When i untick it for OFF i get this :

```
0
```

It totalPrice is > 48 and i tick the box, i get the output :

```
0.5
0.35
```

And if i untick it, i get :

```
0
0
```

I have no idea why its giving me double values, can someone help me? :)

UPDATE-----

Full jQuery : https://pastebin.com/DYV92cj3

HTML for this section :

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="polybags">I WOULD LIKE POLY BAGGING</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can post your complete JS and HTML code?

Comment: Yep. Looks like the code doesnt give the answers. Needs more context. Sounds like both if and else ifs are executing together. Could mean the function is being called twice, while the totalPrice value is being changed somewhere

Comment: that code can not produce your alleged responses

Comment: Can you try to log to the console at the root level of CalculateAddOnPrice and see how many times it's getting called when you tick/untick?

Comment: @Merigold I have no idea how i'd do that...i'm sorry!

Comment: Add `console.log('I was called!')` below `function calculateAddOnPrice() {` to check how many times the function is being called when triggered by the checkboxes

Comment: I seen that pastebin is more complex code than this. Since you said double value. Please add this class name string to your console.log for easy debug

Comment: Also your double output, what line numbers are the log? You should be able to determine the execution flow by looking at the code line number of the log.

Comment: @Merigold when i check the box, i get "I was called!" twice

Comment: Something is obviously wrong with your function call. You should also try to log the value of the `totalPrice` along with that. `console.log("I was called", totalPrice)`

Comment: Ok i get this : 0.5, I was called 1, 0.5, I was called 10

Comment: Okay I'm confused. Where did you put the log? Make sure it's above the rest of the code block and below the function name. Also, I only need to see the console.log that I requested to add. Also, you dont seem to have any problems when the value is below 47, so trigger the function with a value higher than that

Comment: @Merigold ive added it there, the numbers are the totalPrice values, ive just tried adding a single digit, a double digit and a triple digit number to the totalPrice, and on each increment, a new instace of "I was called" is added, so if the totalPrice value is 103 for example, i get 3 instances of "I was Called"

Comment: I think I know your problem. I am NOT too sure as I only secondarily code in jQuery. But you are executing the WHOLE codeblock when you start typing stuff on `.size_control`. That means the functions are being attached to the `change` event of the checkboxes every time you input on the size control elements. Three inputs means the change events are being stacked three times thus three function calls you get.

Comment: @Merigold i added "60" as the value for totalPrice, this was the console output : I was called 6, I was called 60

Comment: Yep. That's your problem. Your function calls are being stacked because of the input event of .size-controls. I suggest a refactor.

Comment: You need to put the change events and `CalculateAddOnPrice()` outside of the  input event of `.size_controls`.

Comment: Thankyou for your time and efforts, ill start looking into it a bit more :)

Comment: @Merigold so i closed off the initial function, now i get the error "totalPrice is not defined" when ever i click lol how do i keep that value alive?

Comment: You can make it global. Currently, `totalPrice` is only defined inside the function of the .size_control input event.

Comment: if you have other variables that are also undefined, it might you have tons of variables that are defined inside the input event. You might want to put everything on the global scope. You can encapsulate the variables into an object for cleanliness too.

Comment: @Merigold the reason its on .size_control is because thats where it gets the values for totalPrice from, am i missing what you're saying here? :( lol sorry!

Comment: Currently you have `var totalPrice = 0` inside the size_control, all you have to do is put that outside the size_control, and let size_control access it normally like `totalPrice = 9000`. So that other functions can also access totalPrice because it's on the global scope, no more undefined.

Comment: @Merigold if i move it outside, everything stops working, and its just not recognised....so i close off the initial .size_control function with some of these }); then set the var? Or do i need to make a new function for it?

Comment: Everything would stop working since your code relies on a scope of a single block (within the { }). Since you put some lines outside, you have to determine which variables are undefined, and then try to define them outside first before the size control event definition. Like I said, you have to refactor your design and avoid adding a change event multiple times on every input

Comment: After a quick skim totalPrice and finalPrice seems to be the variables you need declared outside. Not totally sure as this is quite a lengthy codebase

Comment: This should give you an idea on how to refactor the code. https://pastebin.com/3bS96AhA

Comment: @Merigold AWESOME! Thankyou so much for your help, its really helped me a lot! :D

Comment: How did you do it? Did you find a use to the pastebin link?

Comment: It the link was on point, can you put it as an answer. I'll post as an answer, would totes appreciate that

Comment: Yeah totally! Go for it! Gave me a really good place to start making this thing work properly! :D

Comment: Yey cool beans. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing the whole codeblock when you start typing stuff on `.size_control`. That means the functions are being attached to the change event of the checkboxes every time you input on the size control elements. Three inputs means the change events are being stacked three times thus three function calls you get.

We put the unnecessary code outside the input event and perhaps put them in functions for a more cleaner approach

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('input', '.size_control', function(event) { sizeControlFunc(); });
    setChkBxEvents();
});
```

https://pastebin.com/3bS96AhA